# Redirect to subdirectory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've searched on here and google and can't seem to get this right.

I have a .htaccess file in root ... I want all address to my site to go to a subdirectory (/foo.com/public_html/) and set the baseDirectory.

```
/.htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /foo.com/public_html/

rewritecond %{http_host} ^bar.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.bar.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
rewriterule ^$ /foo.com/public_html/ [nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursitename\.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursitename.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^$ yoursub-directoryname[L]
```

Comment: that directs me to the correct pages, ie the ones in the subdirectory, however, none of the stylesheets or images are pulled from the correct directory (they are using relative paths such as "themes/default/"

Comment: using RewriteRule ^$ /foo.com/public_html [L]
fixes everything, except that the url shows www.bar.com/foo.com/public_html, I need it to just show www.bar.com

Comment: @lostdev It sounds as if you are using relative paths to your stylesheets and images. In this case you'll need to use a `base` element, or make your paths root-relative.